# Filtering an array retrieved from MySQL after replacing strings

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having a lot of trouble getting this code to work and I was wondering if you guys could take a look at it and maybe see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a URL which contains two variables $buildname, and $author.

These two variables are inserted into a query for Mysql to retrieve a unique row, where it then fetches an array of information for that row. For example, each row would contain information such as:

ID, Author, Buildname, Weapon, Mod1, Mod2 .. Mod 8, Polarity 1, Polarity 2.. Polarity 8, hidden.

I then want to check each value, and see if it is equal to a string such as

"No mod in this slot"

and replace it with

""

So that I can later use array_filter to get rid of that section of the array.

My problem(s) I'm encountering are the following

1. When I fetch the array, and perform a foreach loop which echos each element of the array, it is in duplicate. For example, if I perform

   foreach($info_array as $string)
   {
   echo $string;
   }

I get the results

66SteelyDanSteelyDanAcrid BabiesAcrid BabiesAcridAcridNo mod in this slotNo mod in this slotNo mod in this slotNo mod in this slotNo mod in this slotNo mod in this slot

Where the ID is 6, the author is SteelyDan, the buildname is Acrid Babies, the first mod is No mod in this slot... and so on.

Why is it duplicating like this?

Continuing...

My code to replace these values "n" (which would appear as a polarity value) and "No mod in this slot" (Which would appear as a mod value) is the following:

```
foreach($info_array as &$string)
{
    if($string == "n")
    {
        str_replace("n","","n");
    }
    if($string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        str_replace("No mod in this slot","","No mod in this slot");
    } 
}
```

I would then filter the array to get rid of any empty values.

However, this code isn't performing properly.

If I echo the array after I run the loop, all values are the same.

What the heck am I doing wrong here?? This is my full code:

```
    foreach($info_array as $key => $string)
{
    if($string == "n" || $string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        unset($info_array[$key]);
    }
}

$page_id = $info_array['id'];
$page_author = $info_array['author'];
$page_buildname = $info_array['buildname'];
$page_weapon = $info_array['weapon'];
$page_mod1 = $info_array['mod1'];
$page_mod2 = $info_array['mod2'];
$page_mod3 = $info_array['mod3'];
$page_mod4 = $info_array['mod4'];
$page_mod5 = $info_array['mod5'];
$page_mod6 = $info_array['mod6'];
$page_mod7 = $info_array['mod7'];
$page_mod8 = $info_array['mod8'];
$page_polarity1 = $info_array['polarity1'];
$page_polarity2 = $info_array['polarity2'];
$page_polarity3 = $info_array['polarity3'];
$page_polarity4 = $info_array['polarity4'];
$page_polarity5 = $info_array['polarity5'];
$page_polarity6 = $info_array['polarity6'];
$page_polarity7 = $info_array['polarity7'];
$page_polarity8 = $info_array['polarity8'];
$page_category = $info_array['category'];
$page_description = $info_array['description'];
$page_date = $info_array['date'];
$page_hidden = $info_array['hidden'];

//Check if the accessing user is the same as the page creator. If not, check if page is hidden. If page is hidden, redirect to index.php.

if($_SESSION['username'] != $page_author)
{
    if($page_hidden == y)
    {
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

//Retrieve Page Main Image

$page_main_image = convertImageMainPageWeapon($page_weapon);

//Set up mod and polarity associative arrays


$mod_array = array(

"image_mod1" =>     "$page_mod1",
"image_mod2" =>     "$page_mod2",
"image_mod3" =>     "$page_mod3",
"image_mod4" =>     "$page_mod4",
"image_mod5" =>     "$page_mod5",
"image_mod6" =>     "$page_mod6",
"image_mod7" =>     "$page_mod7",
"image_mod8" =>     "$page_mod8"

);

$polarity_array = array(

"image_polarity1" => "$page_polarity1",
"image_polarity2" => "$page_polarity2",
"image_polarity3" => "$page_polarity3",
"image_polarity4" => "$page_polarity4",
"image_polarity5" => "$page_polarity5",
"image_polarity6" => "$page_polarity6",
"image_polarity7" => "$page_polarity7",
"image_polarity8" => "$page_polarity8"

);

foreach($mod_array as &$string)
{
    if($string != "")
    {
    $string = convertImageMod($string);
    }
}

foreach($polarity_array as &$string)
{
    if($string != "")
    {
    $string = convertImagePolarity($string);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code fixed. The variables are now 'unset' but I receive "undefined index errors"

Thanks!

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Try actually using what str_replace returns `$something = str_replace('n','',$string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting empty values into your array and then later using `array_filter`, why not just remove the array elements:

```
foreach($info_array as $key => $string)
{
    if($string == "n" || $string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        unset($info_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$string = str_replace("n", "", $string);`

Comment: @TobiasKun - Thanks. I got in a hurry because lunch is being served.

Comment: No problem at all. Enjoy your meal ^^

Comment: This works, but when it runs it returns notices:

Notice: Undefined index: polarity8 in C:\web\view_build.php on line 72

... Shouldnt my array_filter take care of these empty values and delete the row of the array which contains an empty value?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the new code. It works very well and I like this as an idea, however, I get these errors:


Notice: Undefined index: mod1 in C:\web\view_build.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: mod2 in C:\web\view_build.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: mod3 in C:\web\view_build.php on line 46

etc.

Later in my code I reference the $info_array because I want to turn each of the strings into image tags. But with nothing set, it sees "undefined index"

See my code -- I'm about to update it

Comment: I think I may be able to figure it out from here. I don't want to use this site as my personal debugging team or anything haha. I gotta learn myself but the comments here definitely helped me out and made the script cleaner and easier to process

thank you!

Comment: I'm retrieving the information from a database in this format:

Mod Name (4)

I want to KEEP this value to use as a caption underneath an image.

Then, I want to format that Mod Name into modname.jpg

That is what I do with the other array.

So I have two arrays, one for the image caption and one for the image. 

But in some cases, not every field is filled in with a Mod Name, so I have to separate out the unentered 'no mod in this slot' type fields, and not include them. This gives me "undefined variable" and "undefined index errors." I want to be able to just type {$mod_array['mod1'] in my

Comment: I was talking about variables like `$page_mod2` that have hard coded numbers and don't seem to do anything except to populate another array, when you filtered array already has keys like `mod2`.

Comment: Later on in the code, in my HTML , i want to be able to type 

$page_mod2 and have it display "Mod Name (4)"
then Underneath, type
$mod_array['mod2']

and have it display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($info_array as &$string)
{
    if($string == "n")
    {
        $string = str_replace("n", "", $string);
    }
    if($string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        $string = str_replace("No mod in this slot", "", $string);
    } 
}
```

[edit]removed quotes surrounding $string in str_replace, added variable assignment, skimmed too much originally and didn't notice this wasn't already done.

Comment: This won't do anything else then the original script because str_replace **returns** the changed string.